# C# Render method for ReportExecutionService Requiring credentials for SSRS report generation

Tags: reporting-services, credentials

The render method in below code is causing this error:  Generate Errorhttp: or more data source credentials required to run the report have not been specified. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: One or more data source credentials required to run the report have not been specified.
I have tried adding credentials to the code updating credentials.  Can anyone help me figure out how to add credentials and fix this issue?
public (bool, string) GenerateReport(ReportRequest reportRequest)
{
Byte[] a1 = new Byte[5];

```
        EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Report1",
             EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
        bool success = false;
        bool genRptSuccess = false;
        bool writeRptSuccess = false;
        string resultMessage = "";

        int ReportQueueId = reportRequest.ReportQueueID;
        string ServerUrl = reportRequest.ServerUrl + "/ReportExecution2005.asmx";
        string ReportPath = reportRequest.ReportPath;
        string ReportFormat = reportRequest.ReportFormat;
        string ReportOutputPath = reportRequest.ReportOutputPath;                       

        ParameterValue[] parameters = reportRequest.parameters;
        // parameters[0].Name = "System";
   
       // parameters[0].Value = "0";
         ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
       rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
       // EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate ReportCreds",
       //   EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
        rs.Url = ServerUrl;

        // Render arguments  
        byte[] resultFileBytes = null;
        string reportPath = ReportPath;
        string format = ReportFormat.Trim();
        string historyID = null;
       //     if (parameters != null)
       // {
       //     foreach (ParameterValue rp in parameters)
       //     {
       //         EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Report000" + "Name: {0}" +  rp.Name + "Value: {0}"+  rp.Value, EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);

       //     }
       // }
       // EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Report000" ,
       //               EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
        // string devInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("../../../ReportRunner.Processor/Resources/ReportRunnerConfig.xml");
        //string devInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:/ReportingSystem/ReportRunnerConfig.xml");
        string devInfo = Properties.Resources.ReportRunnerConfig;

        DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
        string showHideToggle = null;
        string encoding;
        string mimeType;
        string extension;
        Warning[] warnings = null;
        ParameterValue[] reportHistoryParameters = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;
          DataSourceCredentials datasetCredential = new DataSourceCredentials();
          datasetCredential.Name = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
          datasetCredential.UserId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
          datasetCredential.Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        //  DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = new DataSourceCredentials[1];
          credentials[0] = datasetCredential;
        //rs.SetExecutionCredentials2(credentials);
        //rs.Credentials = credentials[1];
        //   ReportExecutionService reportExecutionService = new ReportExecutionService();

        // var creds = new DataSourceCredentials[1];

        // creds[0] new DataSourceCredentials() { datasetCredential.Name = "DynamicDataSource", UserName = ReportUserDomain + @"\" + ReportUserAccount, Password = ReportUserPassword };

        //   reportExecutionService.LoadReport(reportPath, null);
        //     var creds = new DataSourceCredentials[1];

        //  creds[0] = new DataSourceCredentials() { Name = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";, UserId = 
        //ReportingService service = new ReportingService();
       // rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
        ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();
        //reportPath = reportPath.Replace("/", "\\");
        //EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Report3"+ reportPath,
        //   EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
        rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;
        execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath.Trim(), historyID);
        
        rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");
        String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

        resultMessage = "SessionID: " + rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;
        Console.WriteLine("SessionID: {0}", rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID);
        //EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Report4",
        //   EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
       // EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate ReportXXY" + "parameters1" + parameters[0].Name + parameters[0].Value  +"parameters2" + parameters[1].Name + parameters[1].Value + "parameters3" + parameters[2].Name + parameters[2].Value + "parameters4" + parameters[3].Name + parameters[3].Value + "parameters5" + parameters[4].Name + parameters[4].Value, EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
        try
        {  if (format == "WORDOPENXML") format = "WORD";
           // EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "parameters" + parameters + "report" + reportPath + "format" + format + "devInfo"+devInfo,
           // EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
            resultFileBytes = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
            execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();
          //  EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Report5",
          // EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
            if (resultFileBytes == null)
            {
              //  EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Report6",
              //EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
                RS_QueueService rs_QueueService = new RS_QueueService();
                string processErrorMessage = "Render Report is null   ExecutionInfo : " + execInfo;
                rs_QueueService.UpdateIsProcessingError(genRptSuccess, ReportQueueId, processErrorMessage);
            }
            else
            {
              //  EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Report7" + "parameters" + parameters + "report" + reportPath + "format" + format + "devInfo" + devInfo,
              //EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
                genRptSuccess = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("SecondSource", "Generate Error" + ServerUrl+"aa"+reportRequest.ReportOutputFileName+"BB" + e.Message+e.InnerException,
            EventLogEntryType.Error, 777, 777, a1);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.OuterXml);

            RS_QueueService rs_QueueService = new RS_QueueService();
            string processErrorMessage = e.Message + "  ExecInfo : " + execInfo;
            rs_QueueService.UpdateIsProcessingError(genRptSuccess, ReportQueueId, processErrorMessage);

        }
```

I tried adding credentials to the c# but not sure how to do this.  I updated credentials in SSRS. Expecting render method to process SSRS report.